# Use of action hint ActionHint in CodeRush

Tags: coderush

I wanted to point the action hint arrow to the methodcall named MyMethod in the current class. So if there are any methodcall with name MyMethod the arrows should be pointing them when I click some combination of keys.

1. I tried to do this with ActionHint steps given [here.](http://www.skorkin.com/2010/11/dxcore-components-actionhint/) But I have no idea which event to use.
2. Then I tried to call CodeRush.ActionHint.PointTo() through CodeProvider but did not work.

Is it possible to write such plugin? If yes which version of PointTo() method should I use.

A sample code if possible would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason for which the action hint doesn't appear is that your source code point might be outside of the visible screen bounds. Before calling PointTo(), make sure that the target point is visible. You can use the following PointTo overload:

```
CodeRush.TextViews.Active.MakeVisible(MyMethodInstance.NameRange);
CodeRush.ActionHint.PointTo(MyMethodInstance.NameRange.Start, "MyMethod", Color.Red);
```

Comment: Thank You Alex, This did not work....Is this feature available with CodeRush Express?

Comment: Yes, it is available with CodeRush Xpress. Could you please share your plug-in for investigation? You can e-mail it at "alex at skorkin dot com".

Comment: BTW, what event of your code provider do you use, in which you are trying to show an action hint?

Comment: I've created a simple code provider and it works OK for me. Here's the code:    private void codeProvider1_CheckAvailability(object sender, CheckContentAvailabilityEventArgs ea)
    {
      ea.Available = ea.Method != null;
    }

    private void codeProvider1_Apply(object sender, ApplyContentEventArgs ea)
    {
      CodeRush.ActionHint.PointTo(ea.Method.NameRange.Start, "MyMethod", Color.Red);
    }

Comment: Thank You Alex, I was trying with GetFeatureAssistanceEventArgs ea in **Action Hint**, which was difficult. But this code you have given worked fine. To use key combination, I used the events of **Action** CheckActionAvailabilityEventArgs and ExecuteEventArgs. Now the key combination also works fine . Thank You once again, have a nice weekend....:)